# ubuntu 14.04 ssh multiple port issue

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I am having an odd issue with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Kernel: 3.13.0-170-generic) and configuring multiple ssh ports.  It answers first port '22' from any interface, but seems to only answers the second port '4422'  via the localhost interface, i.e. "ssh @localhost".  Any suggestions would be great.

I've added the standard port entries in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.  for ports '22' and '4422'. I've kept the defaults ListenAddress.

```
 # What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
 Port 22
 Port 4422
 # Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
 #ListenAddress ::
 #ListenAddress 0.0.0.0enter code here
```

I've check netstat -plan and sshd have locked to the correct port and interface.

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1090/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4422            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1090/sshd
```

Attempts to connect to port 4422 via any interface except lo ssh fails to answer.  You can see the packets are coming into the interface, so no firewall issues via tcpdump.

Again, any help would be great.

Also to note, due to requests by my developer team we are stuck with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Please do not ask, its long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be Ferm causing an iptables issue.

Comment: Some expansion on the root cause would be beneficial to future readers of this question.